# React - how to trigger focus on parent element when the child element is focusing

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

This is my current SearchBar
[image]

What I want to do is, when I focus the `<InputBase>`, it will help to trigger the focus on 
`<div className={classes.search} ref={refSearchBar}></div>`, and make the box-shadow changes like below:

[image]

I tried to use `UseRef`, but it seems not working.

SearchBar.js

```
import React, { useRef } from "react";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import InputBase from "@material-ui/core/InputBase";
import SearchIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Search";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  search: {
    position: "relative",
    borderRadius: theme.shape.borderRadius,
    padding: "0 0.5rem",
    width: "50%",
    border: "1px solid grey",
    "&:focus": {
      boxShadow: "0 0 0 1px blue, 0 0 0 4px blue"
    }
  },
}));

export default function PrimarySearchAppBar(props) {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const refSearchBar = useRef(null);

  return (
    <div className={classes.search} ref={refSearchBar}>
      <div className={classes.searchIcon}>
        <SearchIcon />
      </div>
      <InputBase
        placeholder="Search…"
        classes={{
          root: classes.inputRoot,
          input: classes.inputInput
        }}
        inputProps={{ "aria-label": "search" }}
        style={{ width: "100%" }}
        onClick={() => {
          refSearchBar.current.focus();
        }}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

CodeSandbox
https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-monad-w4cxi?file=/src/SearchBar.jsx

Comment: Do you really want to move the focus to that element or do you just want to style that element differently when it contains the focused element?

Comment: @Quentin All I want is to add the `box-shadow`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The :focus-within CSS pseudo-class matches an element if the element or any of its descendants are focused. In other words, it represents an element that is itself matched by the :focus pseudo-class or has a descendant that is matched by :focus. (This includes descendants in shadow trees.)

— [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus-within)

Thus:

```css
div {
  margin: 1em;
  padding: 1em;
  border: solid blue 3px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

div:focus-within {
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 15px 5px #000000;
}
```

```html
<div><input></div>
<div><input></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**You could add input icon by using [`startAdornment` props](https://material-ui.com/api/input-base/) from InputBase instead**

Because `focus` pseudo-class is only available on input so you would need to apply it to input.

Something like this:

```
<InputBase
  startAdornment={<SearchIcon />}
  placeholder="Search…"
  classes={{
    adornedStart: classes.searchIcon,
    root: classes.inputRoot,
    input: classes.inputInput,
  }}
  inputProps={{ "aria-label": "search" }}
  style={{ width: "100%" }}
/>;
```

Working Example:

[image: Edit cranky-morning-5jpbc]

Comment: The searchIcon is actually a button

Comment: And I will use it to search in the future

Comment: You can surely add an `onClick` event to it. I updated the sanbox.